# How could I script in Javascript (preferably) the eclipse command: Import/Check out Maven Projects from SCM using eclipse ease

Tags: javascript, eclipse, scripting

I looked and I cannot find out how to do this.  Eclipse does this using wizards and job and quite honestly, it is way too complicated to understand easily.  Any example would be much appreciated.  I do not want to have to write a plugin to do this and please do not ask me to do this in groovy or some other language unless it is impossible in Javascript.

By the way, the EASE support page says to create the question using the ease tag but since it does not exist and since I do not have enough points I cannot create it.

Comment: Sounds like [Eclipse Oomph](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Oomph_Authoring) would be better suited for this (Oomph is very powerful, but unfortunately also more difficult to get started with than EASE).

Comment: I disagree.  Although oomph has project creation ability it is if I am not mistaken only supported for Git and does not provide interactive processing.  One would have to prepare setup files and have the user run them which is not the same as running an EASE script.  I would like to know if this is possible with EASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EASE provides support for checkout/import up to some degree.

**Option 1:**
Use the /System/Git scripting module for git checkouts:

```
loadModule("/System/Git");
clone("https://github.com/Pontesegger/codeandme.git", "C:\\test");
importProject("C:\\test\\ui\\TableViewer DnD Sorting");
```

The module /System/SVN provides similar functionality for SVN repositories.

**Option 2:**
Use an existing EGit/Subversive/... command. The /System/Platform module allows to execute any registered eclipse command:

```
loadModule("/System/Platform");
executeCommand("eclipse.project.command.id")
```

This could be used to mimic clicks in the UI as any toolbar button/menu entry in eclipse triggers a command. The Eclipse Plugin-spy might help in detecting command ids.